# Decorator pattern that replace behaviour instead of adding

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

I've read a lot of posts and understand that decorator pattern is supposed to add functionality to the existing object. However, I have a scenario where one behaviour is replaced, not extended.
To demonstrate, assume that I have these classes:

```
public interface IDoStuff {
    string DoStuff();
    string DoOtherStuff();
}

public class A : IDoStuff {
    public A(){}
    public string DoStuff() {
        ....
    }

    public string DoOtherStuff() {
        ....
    }
}


public class B : IDoStuff {
    protected readonly IDoStuff decoratee;

    public B(IDoStuff decoratee){ 
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public string DoStuff() {
        decoratee.DoStuff();
        //More code
    }

    public string DoOtherStuff() {
        ....
        // This does not call decoratee.DoOtherStuff
    }
}
```

While I decorated the `B.DoStuff` method, but its `DoOtherStuff` method is a totally different implementation and cannot reuse the base object at all.

Am I implementing it correctly? Or is this an entirely different pattern?

Comment: What benefit is the `decoratee` providing here? If `B` is a child class of `IDoStuff` and implements the same API, then standard inheritance and polymorphism will suffice. What need for a decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator pattern uses delegation to implement its methods. In a pure version:

> The decorator forwards requests to the component and may perform additional actions (such as drawing a border) before or after
>   forwarding. (Design Patterns, GoF, 1997, *Decorator pattern*)

We can deduce that every method of the decorated class should be used by the decorator, and new method added. It seems that you are not using the plain decorator pattern, but just a delegation pattern. This is very frequent in real world: you build your application with chunks of different patterns to achieve the fixed goal.

Nevertheless, the more important is to stick with the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): `B.doStuff` and `B.doOtherStuff` *must* observe the `IDoStuff` contract (I assume `A.doStuff` and `A.doOtherStuff` do), so that you can use an instance of `B` instead of an instance of `A` without breaking your program logic. (That's a very vague formulation of the Liskov substitution principle, but it should be sufficient here.)